# А если присуждать награду за конкурсный вопрос некому?

Tags: поддержка, конкурс

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать, если присуждать баллы репутации в качестве награды за конкурсный вопрос попросту некому? Конкурс закончился. Был бы рад вручению награды, однако ответ есть лишь один, но и он оказывается не полезным. Что в таком случае необходимо делать? Благодарю за консультацию!

Comment: Так "некому" или "один, но неполезный"? Это всё же разные сценарии. В первом случае делать ничего не надо, но баллы просто "сгорают". См. [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty): потраченная репутация не возвращается, если на конкурсный вопрос никто не ответит. Во втором случае система сама присвоит этому ответу после периода щедрости.

Comment: @A K Это отличный ответ

Comment: Стоит уточнить, что награда присуждается автоматически, если на единственном ответе более 2 плюсов (если не ошибаюсь).

Answer (score 7):

> Так не доставайся ж ты никому!

А. Н. Островский, «Бесприданница»

---

Вообще не выдавайте награду. Награда на плохом ответе будет создавать впечатление, что ответ настолько хорош, что его аж наградили.

А ещё можно пойти в чат и написать: «репутация пропадает зря, дайте кто-нибудь хороший ответ». Вдруг получится.

Comment: @Sevastopol' это вы так витиевато обвинили меня в токсичности?

Comment: @Sevastopol' спасибо, и вам всего хорошего.